# Unable to pass python variable to go binary

Tags: python, go, binary

In my python script I am trying to pass a variable to a Go binary to perform an operation and retrieve output from Go binary as variable and use it in my python script

This is my Go Program which I am using to create my binary and I am creating binary

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strconv"

    ps "github.com/mitchellh/go-ps"
)

var args_pid string
var xyz int

func main() {
args_pid = os.Args[1]

    first, err := strconv.ParseInt(args_pid, 10, 0)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(2)
    }
    xyz = int(first)
    pp, _ := ps.FindProcess(xyz)
    log.Printf("The pid of passed process is %v\n", pp.Pid())
}
```

This is my python script where I am using this binary

```
import os
args_pid = 1401
cmd = './process_pid args_pid'
so = os.popen(cmd).read()
print so
```

I get the following error: 
`strconv.ParseInt: parsing "args_pid": invalid syntax`

Can someone help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
args_pid = 1401
cmd = './process_pid {}'.format(args_pid)
so = os.popen(cmd).read()
print so
```

You passed string args_pid to the Go binary instead of the actual value.

---

When it comes to passing the answer, I'd go with something like this: your Go program could print the PID to stdout using `fmt.Printf("%d", pp.Pid())`.

Then what your Python code does to retrieve the answer is ok. You just need to cast it to int: `so = int(os.popen(cmd).read())`

Comment: Thanks for the solution, It works fine but the second part of my question was that how do I retrieve output from Go binary i.e ```pp.Pid()```  and use it as variable in my python script